# Why use the <g>'s tag in SVG if you use only one element inside?

Tags: svg

source: https://codepen.io/junior/pen/RWQver

As in the following demo:

```css
.completion {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;

  animation: dash 3s linear alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
  
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="76px" height="68px" viewBox="0 0 76 68" enable-background="new 0 0 76 68" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 22.9209 43.4141)" fill="#2EA2DC" font-family="'SFUIText-Bold'" font-size="18">45%</text>
</g>
<path fill="none" stroke="#222729" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M16.652,65.29
 C8.984,58.838,4.112,49.171,4.112,38.366c0-19.424,15.746-35.171,35.17-35.171c19.424,0,35.17,15.747,35.17,35.171
 c0,10.805-4.872,20.473-12.54,26.924"/>
<path class="completion" fill="none" stroke="#2EA2DC" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M17.107,65.29
 C9.44,58.838,4.567,49.171,4.567,38.366C4.567,20.6,17.74,5.911,34.852,3.532"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 21.3916 51.7891)" fill="#222729" font-family="'SFUIText-Light'" font-size="8">completion</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Have you created the svg? If not, the author might was going to add some more elements or deleted them and forgot, or used a tool which autowraps it in <g>s

Comment: You can safely remove the <g> tag, it doesn't serve to anything :)

Comment: Another good reason you might have a `<g>` here is because you want to apply a CSS `transform` animation to the text, but don't want to lose the transform it already has.  It is common to add a `<g>` so that you can apply the transform to that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could have been made by accident or there have been more elements before. The 'G' element in SVG is used to group items together. In this case you can remove the item without breaking stuff.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g